# Slash missing before wp-content & Some uploaded images are not showing?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Slash missing before WP-content & Some uploaded images are not showing?

For Example:
URL:
www.example.comwp-content/uopload/2017

In this website some images not working

Comment: please describe more, full code with site url.

Comment: We have no idea. You need to post the relevant code.

Comment: you have issue in image upload only or pages also?

Comment: i Uploaded images no issue found ..but after two days that images not shown ... images path url / missing

Comment: are you using any plugin for image upload?

Comment: Not using plugins ....uploaded via media library only

Comment: im not sure. need more information or code

Comment: www.example.com/wp-content/uopload/2017/03/ images.png   this image URL path  ....after two days that image url changed to  www.example.comwp-content/uopload/2017/03/ images.png ........

Comment: Missing slash before wp-content

Comment: `.after two days that image url changed ` it wont change automatically

Comment: yes it change automatically

Comment: can you share me the url?

Comment: check any site url mentioned in wp-config.php file..

Comment: give us your site url so that we can check for you. some strangness going on here.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's a bit late for you OP, but anyone facing a similar issue and comes across this post, this may be because of a redirection rule in your web server.

I had http redirecting to https and my rule was missing the trailing slash in my new URL, e.g. for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
...
```

Fix this by adding the trailing slash:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
...
```

Comment: Maybe late for the OP but not late for everyone else. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

if your url completely looking like that :  `http:="" localhost="" mywebsite="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2020="" 08="" finance.jpg"`

you should fix quotes from href.

wrong = `style="background-image:url("<?php echo $imageuri['url'] ?>")"`

correct = `style="background-image:url('<?php echo $imageuri['url'] ?>')"`

with `"` you finishing style quotes